# PHP Counter Using OOP

Tags: php, class

I'm new to OOP terminology, I am trying to create a class that make a hit counter.

I try the code below but it create just a counter.txt page with inside value 1. I dont know why its not incrementing.

```
class LOGFILE {
    public function READ($FileName) {
        $handle = fopen($FileName, 'r');
        $fread = file_get_contents($FileName);
        return $fread;
        fclose($handle);
    }
    public function WRITE($FileName, $FileData) {
        $handle = fopen($FileName, 'w');
        $FileData = $fread +1;
        fwrite($handle, $FileData);
        fclose($handle);
    }
}
$logfile = new LOGFILE();

$logfile -> WRITE("counter.txt",$FileData);

echo $logfile -> READ("counter.txt");
```

Comment: Please use PascalCase for class, also there is no $FileData

Comment: This code is a perfect example of a file access race condition.  This counter will frequently corrupt itself and inaccurately count new hits.  The file should be kept [locked](http://php.net/flock) throughout the read/write process.

Comment: Why the spaces around `->`? Doesn't this code throw any error?

Comment: @Laurent It won't throw any error. Still awful to read.

Comment: @Charles ya i lock it by using fclose, isn't it a good method ?

Comment: @PLB thanks for answering to Laurent :)

Comment: Will `fclose($handle)` execute after a return in the READ function? I was of the belief that return is a final statement in a function. All code after a return point is excluded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `$fread` is local variable for both `READ` and `WRITE` methods. You need to make it `private` global variable for your class:

```
class LOGFILE {
    private $fread;

    public function READ($FileName) {
        $this->fread = file_get_contents($FileName);
        return $this->fread; 
    }
    public function WRITE($FileName) {
            $this->READ($FileName);
        $handle = fopen($FileName, 'w');
        $FileData = $this->fread +1;
        fwrite($handle, $FileData);
        fclose($handle);
    }
}
$logfile = new LOGFILE();

$logfile -> WRITE("counter.txt");

echo $logfile -> READ("counter.txt");
```

**Note:** I have removed `fopen` and `fclose` because `file_get_contents` does not need it. In write you can use [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php). Removed not used variable `$FileData` too. It's always a good practice to create variables methods and classes when they are needed.

Also take a look at best practices how to name your classes, variables, methods and so on. [Here's best guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.html), IMO.

Comment: it also do not increment value, it just create file with value 1

Comment: Shouldn't you do READ, WRITE, READ in order to increment the counter? Otherwise fread is just set to 0+1 when you increment it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start going over the corrected code and see what was missing:

```
<?php

class LOGFILE {

    public function READ($FileName) {
        $handle = fopen($FileName, 'r');
        $fread = fgets($handle, 8192);
        fclose($handle);
        return $fread;        
    }

    public function WRITE($FileName, $FileData) {        
        $counter = $this->READ($FileName);        
        $handle = fopen($FileName, 'w');        
        fwrite($handle, $FileData + $counter);
        fclose($handle);
    }
}
$logfile = new LOGFILE();
$FileData = 1;
$logfile -> WRITE("counter.txt",$FileData);
echo $logfile -> READ("counter.txt")."\n";
$logfile -> WRITE("counter.txt",$FileData);
echo $logfile -> READ("counter.txt")."\n";

?>
```

1. use of `fgets` instead of `file_get_contents` in READ (you can choose to use  `file_get_contents` but I rather stay consistent with the other function that uses `fopen`)
2. use of READ inside function WRITE (the principal of code-reuse)
3. open of file with write permissions in WRITE: `'w'`
4. init `$FileData = 1;`
5. no need to hold a private member: `$fread`
6. most important: do not write statements after `return` (like you did in READ) - statements that are written after `return` will not be executed!

This solution was tested successfully.

Comment: thanks a million for that, i want to ask what is 8192 in line $fread = fgets($handle, 8192);

Comment: it's the size of the buffer (in bytes, default is 1024) you're using in order to read the file

Comment: first time when we run this script it gives error bcuz it request $counter = $this->READ($FileName); before counter.txt creation. Is it possible to remove this error

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it - but you can add a check, and if `$this->READ($FileName);` returns `FALSE` init `counter` to `1`

Answer (score 0):

OOP must be used where it's needed. You need a simple thing so, no need of OOP.

```
<?php

function addValue($file='counter.txt', $amount=1) {
    if( false == is_file($file) ) {
        return false;
    }
    $initial = file_get_contents($file);
    return @file_put_contents($initial+$amount);
}

addValue();

?>
```

Test your OOP knowledge on something complex, like a shopping cart or some other concept.

**EDIT** // so, if you need a simple example that looks complex, here you go :)

```
<?php

class log {

    public $file = '';
    private $amount = 0;

    public function __construct( $file ) {
        $this->file = $file;
        $this->amount = 1;
    }

    public function makeAdd() {
        $initial = file_get_contents($this->file);
        return @file_put_contents($this->file, $initial + $this->amount);
    }

    function __call($f, $args) {
        switch( $f ) {
            case 'add':
                if(isset($args[0]) && !empty($args[0])) {
                    $this->amount = (int)$args[0];
                }
                if( $this->amount == 0 ) {
                    throw new Exception('Not a valid amount.');
                }
                return $this->makeAdd();
            break;
        }
    } 

}

try {

    // create log
    $L = new log('count.txt');

    // this will add 2
    var_dump($L->add(2));

    // this will also add 2
    var_dump($L->add());

    // until you rewrite the amount
    var_dump($L->add(1));

    // final result -> 5

} catch(Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}

?>
```

Good luck!

Comment: i can do it with simple function like how you do that, but i'm learning OOP so can you help me in my code :)

Answer (score 0):

- Use UpperCamelCase for class names. `LogFile`, not `LOGFILE`. When you have a variable and the most interesting thing about it is that it's expected to hold a reference to something that `is_a` `LogFile` you should name it `logFile`.
- Use lowerCamelCase for functions. read and write, not READ and WRITE
- No spaces around the arrow operator
- Code after a return statement in a method can never be reached, so delete it.
- read() does not use the handle returned by fopen, so don't call fopen
- the temp variable $freed doesn't help us understand the code, so we can lose it
- read is a slightly unconventional name. If we rename the function to getCount it will be more obvious what it does.
- You said you wanted to make a hit counter. So rename the class from LogFile to HitCounter, and the variable to hitCounter
- the $FileData parameter to write doesn't get used because the variable is re-assigned inside the function. We can lose it.
- The write method is supposed to add one to the number in the file. Write doesn't really express that. Rename it to increment.
- Use a blank line between functions. The procedural code at the end should generally be in a separate file, but here we can just add a couple of extra lines. Delete the blanks between the last three lines of code.
- Don't repeat yourself - we shouldn't have to mention 'counter.txt' more than once. OOP is all about combining data structures and behaviour into classes, so make a class private variable to hold the filename, and pass it via a constructor
- $fread doesn't exist in the scope of increment, so we can't use it. This won't work. Replace it with a call to to getCount()
- Swap the first two lines of increment, so we're not doing two concurent accesses to the same file, although we might be running inside a server that's running our script twice and still doing two concurrent accesses.
- Rename the variable $FileData to $count, since that's what it is.
- Replace the fopen,fwrite,fclose sequence with file_put_contents, since that does the same thing and is more succinct.

  - We need  tag, since our php code continues to the end of the file.

That leaves us with:

```
<?php

class HitCounter {
    private $fileName;

    public function __construct($fileName){
      $this->fileName = $fileName;
    }

    public function getCount() {
        return file_get_contents($this->fileName);
    }

    public function increment() {
        $count = $this->getCount() + 1;
        file_put_contents($this->fileName, $count);
    }
}


$hitCounter = new HitCounter("counter.txt");    
$hitCounter->increment();    
echo $hitCounter->getCount();
```

Comment: I realise now this site is stackoverflow. I was thinking it was codereview.stackexchange when I wrote this.

Answer (score -3):

**You can create a static counter and increment it each time** (instead of create file)

```
<?php
class CountClass {
    public static $counter = 0;

    function __construct() {
        self::$counter++;
    }
}

new CountClass();
new CountClass();


echo CountClass::$counter;
?>
```

Comment: i can create with simple function also, but i'm learning oop. So can you please take a look at my code. Thank you for your reply :)

Comment: And that won't work anyway since the counter won't persist from one request to another.

Comment: @Nirav Ranpara its OOP and your code is also not working. I need to create .txt file for some purpose